# Do i have to add Overflow in my Stack widget?

Tags: flutter

I have watched tutorials on how to use Flutter Stack widget but I don't see them using `OverFlow` in their code, but when I start writing mine, the top objects clip or hide inside the bottom object, except when I use `OverFlow.visible` before they leave each other, please what is the course of this issue?

Comment: Can you please describe your issue with relevant code snippet?

Answer (score 0):

`Stack` widget default to `Overflow.clip`. If you want different behaviour you can change it.

[From doc](https://api.flutter.dev/flutter/widgets/Stack/Stack.html):

> Implementation
>
> ```
> Stack({
>   Key key,
>   this.alignment = AlignmentDirectional.topStart,
>   this.textDirection,
>   this.fit = StackFit.loose,
>   this.overflow = Overflow.clip,
>   List<Widget> children = const <Widget>[],
> }) : super(key: key, children: children);
> ```